# How to escape '|' in emacs's org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-table

I want to make a table in org-mode.

Like this
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfIUX.png), I want to input ‘|’ in the table, how can I escape '|' in emacs?

Comment: Thank you! That's the answer.

Comment: I am not sure why you need to escape the pipe character. In an orgmode table the pipes are used and recognized for where to put the separators. http://orgmode.org/manual/Built_002din-table-editor.html#Built_002din-table-editor